# jQuery : CSS smooth transition on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want create a navbar that can change the `background-color` when scroll on spesific `scrollTop`. It's working perfectly, but I want add a transition between change both color. It's mean when I scroll more and more to bottom the navbar background-color getting blue. Here's my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7efc61qs/.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to change background slowly on scroll number or just longer transition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var div = $('.red');
var limit = 500;
$(window).scroll(function(){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   div.css({ 'opacity' : (1 - st/500) });
})
```

```css
.red {
  background:red;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:20px;
}

.blue {
  position:fixed;
  background:blue;
  height:20px;
  width:100%;
}
.content {
  height:20px;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blue">
</div>
<div class="red">
</div>
<div class="content">
 a b c
</div>



<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

when scrolltop reaches 500px then opacity of div.red is 1 - 500/500 = 0

Comment: Yes it working but I want at scrollTop > 10 it has purple background, scrollTop > 50 it has darkblue background, and scrollTop > 230 it has blue background for example

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out *Scrollie*

Funsella made a great example over at CodePen for you to play with:
https://codepen.io/Funsella/pen/yLfAG

```
$( window ).ready(function() {

var wHeight = $(window).height();

$('.slide')
  .height(wHeight)
  .scrollie({
    scrollOffset : -50,
    scrollingInView : function(elem) {

      var bgColor = elem.data('background');

      $('body').css('background-color', bgColor);

    }
  });
```

});

Link to Scrollie on GitHub